# Update all documents in a collection in Firestore based on search criteria in Swift 4, Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know how to update the individual document in a collection based on a search string in Firebase Cloud Firestore.

I have a collection "Recent", which has the following fields;

- id: primary key
- chatRoomId: string
- blockStatus: string with value (yes/ no)

I am able to list down the all the documents to update based on

```
func blockChat(_ recent: RecentChat) {
    FirebaseReference(.Recent).whereField("chatRoomId", isEqualTo: recent.chatRoomId).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("DEBUG: Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("DEBUG: \(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                print("DEBUG: \(document.data().count)")

                FirebaseReference(.Recent).updateData(["blockChat" : "yes"])

            }
        }
    }
}
```

how do I update the documents in the collection for a field "blockStatus" based on my search of a string in field chatRoomId? for example if chatRoomId for two documents is equal to "abcd", then the blockStatus field for both the documents will be updated to "Yes" from the default "no"

Comment: The question is very unclear. Collections do not have elements. Collections have Documents and Documents have Fields. Also, in the provided code, no Array is created - what you have is each document in querySnapshot.documents, which, according to your question is only 2 documents. But the question asks *how to update the individual document* but there are 2. If you can clarify the question (please update the question itself) we'll take a look and see if we can help. And where is the code that actually writes data?

Comment: @Jay - thanks for the feedback, updated the question

Comment: I formatted your code for you.The question states that the Recent collection has fields but collections (as mentioned above) have documents - I assume you mean the documents have fields. If you're trying to update the `blockStatus` field in both documents, this won't do it `FirebaseReference(.Recent).updateData(["blockChat" : "yes"])` because it's updating the `blockChat` field, not the `blockStatus` field. Also, if you want to update a specific document, that code won't work as `FirebaseReference(.Recent)` points to a collection, not the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me restate the question;

> I want to query Firestore for documents which contain a chatRoomId
> field equal to a chat room `chatRoomId`. For the matching documents, I
> then want to update a field in each document `blockStatus` with a
> value of "yes"

Here's the code that queries for those documents and updates the field:

```
func updateBlockStatusField() {
    let chatRoomsCollection = self.db.collection("ChatRooms")

    chatRoomsCollection.whereField("chatRoomId", isEqualTo: recent.chatRoomId).getDocuments(completion: { documentSnapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let docs = documentSnapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in docs { //iterate over each document and update
            let docRef = doc.reference
            docRef.updateData(["blockStatus" : "yes"])
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you for explaining the logic so well. truly appreciate you taking the time, thank you.